# How to read trc files from different directory in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a program that reads data from `.trc` files. But as of now, it can only read the `.trc` files that are in the current directory i.e the MATLAB folder. If I want it to read a file, I have to copy the file in MATLAB folder. Is there a way I can move to different directories and choose another `.trc` file? I have tried using `dir`, `uigetdir` etc. but nothing seems to work!

Comment: It's impossible to determine what you're doing incorrectly without an example of what you tried and the error(s) received.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward to filter results with the `dir` command with a file extension if you specify the folder to search with a wildcard character in place of the file name.  You can then loop over the generated list of file names in the output structure (as shown) or whatever you need to do with those files.

```
folderName = 'C:\Path\To\Target\Folder\';
fileList = dir(strcat(folderName, '*.trc'));

for k = 1:length(fileList)

    fileHere = fullfile(folderName, fileList(k).name);
    % Do what you need with the files in here

end
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this using cd (change directory)? Your method isn't working either, for some reason. It always says 'File not found'. That's the message it is supposed to generate when fid=-1.

Comment: You can use the `cd` command to do something similar.  What I posted will not ever generate the 'File not found' error because if no files are found matching the search criteria the code will simply not enter the for loop.  The error must be in your code but I can't diagnose it unless you post what that code is.